# Copying a #defined string into a structure array

Tags: c, string

I have a structure as:

```
//GUID structure
typedef struct {
    var8 octet[16];
} GPTGUID_t;
```

And a long #define as:

```
#define PTYPE_MRP_UPPER     0x4db80b5ce3c9e316ULL
#define PTYPE_MRP_LOWER     0xae1502f02df97d81ULL
```

I wish to copy UPPER part in octet 0 to 7 and LOWER in 8 to 15.
Unfortunately all attempts including memcpy has failed and given segfault.

I tried something as:

```
        strcpy(guid.octet[0], PTYPE_MRP_UPPER);
        strcpy(guid.octet[8], PTYPE_MRP_LOWER);
```

And also,

```
memcpy(guid.octet[0], PTYPE_MRP_UPPER, sizeof(PTYPE_MRP_UPPER));
memcpy(guid.octet[8], PTYPE_MRP_LOWER, sizeof(PTYPE_MRP_LOWER));
```

Both have failed.

Just as a side note:

```
typedef unsigned char       var8;
typedef unsigned short      var16;
typedef unsigned int        var32;
```

However, I am able to extract the individual octets as:

```
    memcpy( guid.octet, pHdr->partTypeGUID, sizeof(GPTGUID_t));//copy the partitionTypeGUID
    p1 = getvar64(guid.octet[0]);
    p2 = getvar64(guid.octet[8]);
```

where, `#define getvar64(x) (*(var64*)(&x))`

Comment: Read what strcpy does. Read what memcpy does. Pay special attention to the types in their signatures. Your two #defined symbols are unsigned long longs, not strings or pointers. What you are doing is nonsense.

Comment: @SanJacinto: I know that..lol. I just tried everything else as memcpy failed at first instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value `0x4db80b5ce3c9e316ULL` is not a string, so `strcpy` treats is as a pointer and with a value like that it's pointing *way* wrong.

You also can't use `strcpy` as it copies until it finds a zero byte (the character `'\0'`). Use `memcpy` instead.

You also doesn't pass *pointers* to the `memcpy` function, but values. You should turn on more warnings because the compiler will *not* like it, but not enough to make it an error apparently.

Try to call `memcpy` like this:

```
unsigned long long val;

val = PTYPE_MRP_UPPER;
memcpy(&guid.octet[0], &val, sizeof(val));
val = PTYPE_MRP_LOWER;
memcpy(&guid.octet[8], &val, sizeof(val));
```

Comment: @kingsmasher1 That's because you pass a `var8` and an `unsigned long long` values to the function, not pointers. See my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, but why it fails if: `val = PTYPE_MRP_UPPER;  memcpy(&(pHdr->partTypeGUID[0]), &val, sizeof(val));
   val = PTYPE_MRP_LOWER;
   
   memcpy(&(pHdr->partTypeGUID[8]), &val, sizeof(val));`

Comment: `var8 partTypeGUID[16]` is declared inside pHdr struct

Comment: @kingsmasher1 Fails how? Compilation? Runtime? If compilation what errors do you get, if runtime have you tried running it in a debugger to know that this is the place it fails?

Comment: Runtime in all cases, can't run debugger. It's a PXE distro.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 You could make a test program and run locally in a debugger. Also, when doing the debug print calls you could also print all values, all addresses and the sizes, to make sure everything looks valid.

Comment: Yes, but it's quite strange, as how it does not work the other way round. Anyway, will post it here once i find the issue.

Comment: woops !! My bad. pHdr is a pointer, forgot to initialize (malloc) it. So it fails.

Answer (score 1):

These are not memory portions, these are numbers: why not use masks ?

```
int i;
unsigned long long mask = 0xff00000000000000;
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  guid.octet[i] = (PTYPE_MRP_UPPER & mask) >> ((7 - i) * 8);
  guid.octet[i+8] = (PTYPE_MRP_LOWER & mask) >> ((7 - i) * 8);
  mask >>= 8;
}
```

Comment: I think, you need to shift `PTYPE_MRP_UPPER & mask` by the appropriate number of bits right, because this will return ones on positions other the the first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a union:

```
//GUID structure
typedef struct {
    union {
        var8 octet[16];
        uint64_t qword[2];
    };
} GPTGUID_t;

// This copies the bytes in native-endian order; do an endian swap if you need
// non-native order
guid.qword[0] = PTYPE_MRP_UPPER;
guid.qword[1] = PTYPE_MRP_LOWER;
```

Note that this is an anonymous union, which is a feature of the C11 language standard, but it's also implemented as a language extension in many C89/C99 compilers; if your compiler doesn't support that, then you'd have to use a named union instead.

Alternatively, if you can't or don't want to modify the definition of `GPTGUID_t`, you should just copy the bytes in one at a time:

```
// This stores the bytes in big-endian order
guid.octet[0] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_UPPER >> 56);
guid.octet[1] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_UPPER >> 48);
guid.octet[2] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_UPPER >> 40);
guid.octet[3] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_UPPER >> 32);
guid.octet[4] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_UPPER >> 24);
guid.octet[5] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_UPPER >> 16);
guid.octet[6] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_UPPER >> 8);
guid.octet[7] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_UPPER);
guid.octet[8] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_LOWER >> 56);
guid.octet[9] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_LOWER >> 48);
guid.octet[10] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_LOWER >> 40);
guid.octet[11] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_LOWER >> 32);
guid.octet[12] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_LOWER >> 24);
guid.octet[13] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_LOWER >> 16);
guid.octet[14] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_LOWER >> 8);
guid.octet[15] = (var8)(PTYPE_MRP_LOWER);
```

Answer (score -2):

What actually  are   0x4db80b5ce3c9e316ULL and  0xae1502f02df97d81ULL?
Seems you are copying randomly data at specific address.

By the way, if you're actually dealing with string,

```
#define PTYPE_MRP_UPPER     "0x4db80b5ce3c9e316ULL"
#define PTYPE_MRP_LOWER     "0xae1502f02df97d81ULL"
```

should do the trick. (even if i dunno what you really want to do with those values)

Comment: Dear god no, this isn't the answer.  The numbers are numeric literals.  Converting them to strings, 0x prefix and ULL suffix and all, and then memcpying from those, won't possibly work.